# How to get when a view is activated?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

Making it simple, I have a prism module with several view.

One of these is a usercontrol with a grid in it and I need to get when this view is active to reload its datacontext.

I know i have to use the `IActiveAware` interface, but I can't figure out how...

**edit:**

MyUserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="[...]
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <dc:MyViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    [...]
```

MyUserControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl, IActiveAware
{
    public MyUserControl(IRegionManager _regionManager)
    {
        regionManager = _regionManager;
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Activated;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Deactivated;

    private bool _IsActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsActive;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsActive = value;
            IActiveAware vmAware = DataContext as IActiveAware;
            if (vmAware != null)
                vmAware.IsActive = value;

        }
    }
    public event EventHandler IsActiveChanged = delegate { };
[...]
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel: IActiveAware
{
    private bool isActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return isActive;
        }
        set
        {
            isActive = value;
            LoadData();
            IsActiveChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler IsActiveChanged = delegate { };
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the interface on your view model. You'll need to implement the event handler too, but I've left it off this example. You can see a full example on [Brian Noyes's blog](http://briannoyes.net/2009/12/08/detecting-the-active-view-in-a-prism-app/).

```
public class ViewModel : IActiveAware
{
    private bool _isActive;

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return _isActive; }
        set
        {
             _isActive = value;

             // Do Other Stuff e.g.
             LoadData();
        }
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
         .....
    }
}
```

Prism looks at the view model it is activating, and determines whether or not it implements `IActiveAware`, if it does, it's sets `IsActive`, so that you can make the view model, and consequently the view, do stuff.

Comment: thanks, i followed the example but when i change view nothing is triggered... i added my code in the question